# Get HTML/Plain text campaign body using MailChimp API 3.0

Tags: curl, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I can't find out how to get the body of a campaign in the new v3.0 API of MailChimp. I successfully used the `/3.0/campaigns` call to get the title, but I can't frigging get the email content!! Even `/3.0/campaigns/single_campaign_id` gives me all the useless info except the email content... How can I solve this?

I tried the old version ([/campaigns/content.format](https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/campaigns/content.php)), but even though I added "apikey MYAPIKEY" in the header I keep getting the `"You must specify a apikey value"` error. I'm so frustrated.
Am I blind or isn't there a way to extract a campaign html/plain text body in v3.0?

Comment: Did you get a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the [content of campaign's email](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/campaigns/content) by:

```
GET- /campaigns/{campaign_id}/content
```

Comment: Although the documentation mentions the plain_text field, it is never returned in the response. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

It is very odd, but MailChimp does first generate the `plain_text` field when you have send at least one e-mail from the mail-template or campaign. IMO the `plain_text` field should be generated when creating and/or editing the mail template/campaign using `html`.

This put us on the right track: [How to edit the plain text version of a Mailchimp automation email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34802719/how-to-edit-the-plain-text-version-of-a-mailchimp-automation-email)

After sending a test e-mail, the `plain_text` field is available in the API.

**UPDATE**

I have reported this as a bug/unfortunate feature directly to the staff at MailChimp. This was done on february 2nd 2017. They confirmed on february 7th that they would investigate further as a result of the logs they enabled.

With that commen, they closed the case, so I am not sure they have, or ever will, fix the bug.